# How many players can play splitscreen in COD: WWII?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

How many players can play split-screen, and what game modes are (or aren't) available?

- How many players can play local co-op?
- How many players can play local multiplayer?
- How many players can play online multiplayer from a single console?

These questions don't appear to be specifically addressed anywhere on [the website](https://www.callofduty.com/wwii), and I didn't see any mention in any of the reviews I've read. Even the packaging of the game itself (I haven't seen it, basing this claim off of the standard Xbox One game packaging details) only answers the first of these three questions.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this deleted question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/320600/32055), asked as a new question because of these [two](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12679/32055) meta [qustions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6971/32055).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CoD WW2 you can only play locally with up to two players (split screen or not). Modes available are standard multiplayer or Nazi Zombies.

Local co-op and local multiplayer is limited to 2 players only. The Xbox One or PS4 will only accept 2 controllers at a given time for this. The PC version has no local multiplayer support (as of today, November 7).

The amount of players who can play online multiplayer from a single console is also limited to 2 players.

Comment: So no campaign co-op?

Comment: is 3-4 player local coop planned?